# How can I deduce from NSMethodSignature that a struct argument is passed by pointer?

Tags: objective-c, clang, llvm, objective-c-runtime

How can I deduce from `NSMethodSignature` that a struct argument is passed by pointer to the stack?

Specifically on ARM.

For example if I have:

```
@protocol TestProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)time:(CMTime)time;
- (void)rect:(CGRect)point;
@end
```

And then I do:

```
  struct objc_method_description methodDescription1 =
    protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(TestProtocol), @selector(time:), YES, YES);
  struct objc_method_description methodDescription2 =
    protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(TestProtocol), @selector(rect:), YES, YES);

  NSMethodSignature *sig1 = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:methodDescription1.types];
  NSMethodSignature *sig2 = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:methodDescription2.types];

  const char *arg1 = [sig1 getArgumentTypeAtIndex:2];
  const char *arg2 = [sig2 getArgumentTypeAtIndex:2];

  NSLog(@"%s %s", methodDescription1.types, arg1);
  NSLog(@"%s %s", methodDescription2.types, arg2);
```

The output is:

```
v40@0:8{?=qiIq}16 {?=qiIq}
v48@0:8{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}16 {CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}
```

Both look similar, no indication that CMTime will be actually passed as a pointer.

But when I print the debug description:

```
  NSLog(@"%@", [sig1 debugDescription]);
  NSLog(@"%@", [sig2 debugDescription]);
```

The first prints:

```
  ...
  argument 2: -------- -------- -------- --------
        type encoding (^) '^{?=qiIq}'
        flags {isPointer}
  ...
```

While the second prints:

```
  ...
  argument 2: -------- -------- -------- --------
        type encoding ({) '{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}'
        flags {isStruct}
  ...
```

So this information is indeed stored in the method signature, but how do I retrieve it without parsing the debug description? Are there rules I can use to deduce this myself? I tried different structs but it is hard to spot a pattern.

Comment: I have `argument 2: -------- -------- -------- --------
        type encoding ({) '{?=qiIq}'
        flags {isStruct}` May be you have changed method to `(void)time:(CMTime *)time`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH This is implementation dependant. I tested it on an iPhone XS MAX. Did you run it on an non ARM arch?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Looks like it's compiler optimisation for too big structs. I have created struct with several rects and result becomes the same like with `CMTime`. So why do you care how structs passed to methods on the CPU level?

Comment: These "big" structs are not "retained" by default by NSInvocation, only retainArguments will retain them. The current implementation of OCMock has it's own implementation of retaining invocation args. This implementation assumes all structs are like CGRect. I want to update it to copy the problematic arguments to a separate buffer (and later use these when matching invocations), but for this I need to know which struct arguments need to be copied.

Comment: TL;DR I need this info to be able to implement my own version of `NSInvocation retainArguments]`.